# Where are IIS logs when running in Azure development fabric

Tags: iis, azure

I am looking for the IIS error logs (or access logs) while debugging an Azure application in the development fabric.  Where are they?  (Azure SDK 1.8)  I think it is using IIS 8 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IISExpress to run Azure Instance locally, you can launch IISExpress view as below by right clicking the icon in your system tray:

[image]

Once you have it visible, you can see the location where the config file is located and the log files are located at the folder name iisexpress inside above folder:

```
C:\Users\avkashc\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\6bffef53-b946-4d1e-9b38-cf10cdfec118\temp\temp\RoleTemp\iisexpress
```

If you want to see the logs specific to your local deployment you can always look for following folder and then your deployment(NO) folder:

```
C:\Users\avkashc\AppData\Local\dftmp\logs
```

Answer (score 1):

They are available in the local storage emulator account (`devstoreaccount1`) under the `wad-iis-logsfiles` folder as shown in the picture below:

[image: wadiislogfiles]

Comment: Your information is about logs at Azure Storage and the question is about where IIS Express logs are stored locally when running application in development fabric.